VScode ignores launch.json in correct path from wsl with CMake-tools
I'm setting up my VSCode in wsl2 to build and debug my c project with CMakeTools, however even after creating a launch.json file it doesn't apply its contents to debugging.
This is my launch.json:
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.1",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/cipherffff",
            "args": ["a"],
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "config",
                    "value": "Debug"
                }
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

Notice both the program and args fields.
I know it does read the file according to the next command that I ran just before debugging:
$ inotifywait -e open -m .vscode/launch.json
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
.vscode/launch.json OPEN
.vscode/launch.json OPEN
.vscode/launch.json OPEN

and that ignores it's contents according to these debug logs that I've seen in the
output console when starting to debug:
[main] Debug configuration from cache: {"type":"cppdbg","name":"Debug cipher","request":"launch","cwd":"/home/MYUSER/project_name/build","args":[],"MIMode":"gdb","miDebuggerPath":"/usr/bin/gdb","setupCommands":[{"description":"Enable pretty-printing for gdb","text":"-enable-pretty-printing","ignoreFailures":true}],"program":"/home/MYUSER/project_name/build/cipher"}
[main] Starting debugger with following configuration. {"workspace":"file:///home/MYUSER/project_name","config":{"type":"cppdbg","name":"Debug cipher","request":"launch","cwd":"/home/MYUSER/project_name/build","args":[],"MIMode":"gdb","miDebuggerPath":"/usr/bin/gdb","setupCommands":[{"description":"Enable pretty-printing for gdb",....

It really doesn't add any arguments to running the executable in the debugger gui as well.
I'm running the cmake-tools debugger and not the default one.
My work environment versions:
CMake Tools v1.19.52
VScode version 1.94.2
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

are you actually launching the launch configuration you've specified or are you using cmake-tool's run button? see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md

I've tried running it with the CMake: Debug command with and with the Shift+F5 shortcut, as well as through the GUI
